# Can't reach 3th and 4th inner for loops

Tags: java, arrays, image-processing, kernel, blur

```
public static Color[][] blur(int a, Color[][] array){

    System.out.println("here");

    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<array[0].length; j++){

            int rsum = 0;
            int gsum =0;
            int bsum = 0;

            for(int x= i+ 1; x<= i- 1; x++){
                for(int y= j+1; y<= j- 1; y++){

                    if(x >= 0 && x< array.length && y>= 0 && y<array[0].length) {

                        System.out.println("hola");

                        int r = array[x][y].getRed();
                        rsum = rsum + r;

                        int g = array[x][y].getGreen();
                        gsum = gsum + g;

                        int b = array[x][y].getBlue();
                        bsum = bsum + b;

                    }
                }
            }

            int ravg = rsum/a;
            int gavg = gsum/a;
            int bavg = bsum/a;

            array[i][j] = new Color(ravg, gavg, bavg);
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

I'm trying to create a program where in a 2d array of Color pixels, I try to move a 3x3 kernel of 2d array across the bigger 2d array, and set the center pixel value to be the averages of all the rgb values. I've been debugging for hours but this just won't reach the 3rd for loop at all. Can someone please help?

Comment: You start `x` at `i+1`, and loop as long as `x` is less than or equal to `i-1`. `i-1` is less than `i+1`, so your initial state doesn't meet the conditions to enter the loop. Same problem exists with the `y` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop never does anything.

```
for(int x= i+ 1; x<= i- 1; x++){
```

This is because i + 1 <= i - 1 is never true (unless you have an overflow)

What you most likely meant is

```
for (int x= i - 1; x <= i + 1; x++) {
```

or

```
for (int x= i + 1; x >= i - 1; x--) {
```

Comment: Oh sorry that question was silly. Thank you so much!